# Creating a Factory in Typescript using infer and typeof

Tags: typescript, factory, type-inference

**Main Goal:**
I am trying to learn (and understand, not just copy and paste) how to create a Factory in Typescript but have a few points of confusion related to types and type inference. I'd like to
have a "MyCloner" class be able to create multiple instances of an IClonable. For instance if I have a Truck class and a Motorcycle class that both implement IClonable.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
const vehicleCloner = new MyCloner();
const truck = new Truck({color: 'red', fuel: 'electric'});
```

and MyCloner do something like:

```
var myTenElectricTrucks = vehicleCloner.cloneWithRandomColors(truck, 10);
```

**First Point of Confusion (infer and new):**
I have been following a few tutorials, but I don't fully understand this:

```
type ExtractInstanceType<T> = T extends new () => infer R ? R : never;
```

I guess I am not used to this declaration of a type with everything going on. I get that we are declaring some type, with what looks like the ability to take a generic called T. Then it looks like T is extending the function "new" (which as far as I knew is a reserved keyword). But how do R, T and 'new' relate to each other?  I don't get what is going on with the => operator here (is it used to declare a function?)

I am not sure I understand what infer does in Typescript after looking it up.

Here is  [the tutorial for ExtractInstanceType](https://medium.com/codex/factory-pattern-type-script-implementation-with-type-map-ea422f38862) and context

I realize keeping the trucks as electric is extra and not typically part of the Factory pattern as far as I understand but that is ultimately the goal. But I believe that shouldn't be a big step after understanding the basics of infer and ExtractInstanceType.

Thank you for your time.

**Second point of confusion (more type declarations & type literals):**

I am also confused by the following line in [the same tutorial](https://medium.com/codex/factory-pattern-type-script-implementation-with-type-map-ea422f38862).

```
type userTypes = typeof userMap[Keys]; //typeof Developer | typeof Manager
```

To me this looks like it is saying that Keys is not a single key? Usually in JS I would expect that to be a string that gets me a single value in return from a dictionary? But the key in essence is a type literal representing multiple types, which is then is used as a single key somehow?

Here is Keys for reference:

```
type Keys = keyof typeof userMap; // 'dev' | 'manager'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future try to limit yourself to one question per question but the answers to your questions are pretty succinct, so...

Let's turn that conditional type declaration into some psuedo code that more clearly indicates what's going on:

> type InstanceType(T) = **if** T is a class **then** the type of the thing constructed by `new`ing that class **else** type `never`

And lets gradually move back towards the actual code (these are all representations of the same thing):

```js
type InstanceType<T> = (T is a class) ? (thing-T-constructs, i.e. 'R') : never
type InstanceType<T> = (T extends (new () => R)) ? R : never
```

Hopefully seeing the substitutions line by line (like simplifying an equation in math) helps. `T extends new () => R` just means 'T satisfies the constraint that it represents a `new`able thing that returns an `R`' and `R` is just 'the thing the class `T` constructs'. The `never` is just there as a safeguard: in case a caller uses the type incorrectly with a non-class generic parameter.

And now we have *almost* syntactically valid Typescript. But the problem is `R`: it's an undeclared variable which is just as problematic in types as it is in code. That's where the `infer` keyword comes in:

```js
type InstanceType<T> = (T extends (new () => infer R)) ? R : never
// and dropping the grouping parens to arrive back at the original:
type InstanceType<T> = T extends new () => infer R ? R : never
```

Here we tell the compiler to *infer* the type of `R` based on the condition being fulfilled, i.e. that `T` is a class that can be constructed with `new`. N.B. that AFAIK `infer` can *only* be used in the context of conditional types like this.

```js
type Keys = keyof typeof userMap;
```

Here we want to construct a *type* based on the keys in the *value* `userMap`. Since we can't use a value as a type we have to call `typeof` to get the type of userMap and since it's an associative data structure we can call `keyof` to get the *union* of the map keys: `'dev' | 'manager'`.

Then the rest kind of falls into place, we can use an *index type* to get the union of the types of the *values* (in the key/value pair sense) from the map:

```js
type userTypes = typeof userMap[Keys];
```

Which you might think would be `Developer | Manager` but since we're constructing a *type* (`userTypes`) and we can't use values as types, the actual union is `typeof Developer | typeof Manager`.

So to summarize the second part:

```js
typeof userMap;       // Typescript compile-time type of the userMap
keyof typeof userMap; // The type of the *compile-time keys* of userMap
typeof userMap[keyof typeof userMap] // ditto but for the types of the *values* in the map
```

Comment: Thank you this helps. I am still not 100% clear and could probably benefit from extra reading material if you have any.
Perhaps one way to think about it is it hat userMap[Key] is not saying get me the literal value in some dictionary, but rather the type of them?
if we were to expand out keof typeof userMap :
typeof userMap['dev'| 'manager'] 
would that be what I am getting the type of? In this case that

Comment: Will do thank you. I may also post them as 3 different questions to get a deeper understanding. I think this gets me a lot closer to understanding but still not fully there yet.  I need to take a moment to think.

Comment: @JC1700 to answer the question in your comment, yes that is correct. With an index type you don't get the literal value, you get the union of the possible types of the possible values in the map. If you did it with `foo = {a: 1, b: 'hi'}` you'd get `a | b` for `keyof typeof foo` because a and b are the known keys of `foo` and `number | string` for `typeof foo[keyof typeof foo]` because those are the possible values from an object property lookup. Assigning pieces to intermediate types simplifies the expressions, like `Keys` in the tutorial you reference.

Comment: As to your second comment, take your time. Some of this is fairly advanced Typescript, we have thousands and thousands of lines of TS at work and probably not a single use of `infer` in the entire codebase. Although by contrast we use key and index types all the time.

Comment: @JC1700 Check out [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) from the offical docs. Also remember: types *look* like regular code but they really aren't. They're related to regular code but they're their own thing. They have they're own rules and behavior. For better or worse a lot of the syntax overlaps but they are very different than values in code.

Comment: Will do, I appreciate the resources & help, thank you. In the meanwhile I hopefully posted a better follow up question to add the stuff that is still unclear to me. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69691672/what-does-this-return-type-mean-with-infer   Thank you for your time.