# What does this return type with never do vs just using an Interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

In trying to create a factory in Typescript I came across [this article](https://medium.com/codex/factory-pattern-type-script-implementation-with-type-map-ea422f38862) and I am confused by this part :

```
  class UserFactory {
  static getUser(k: Keys) : ExtractInstanceType<userTypes> {
    return new userMap[k]();
  }
```

The type definition for reference:

```
type ExtractInstanceType<T> = T extends new () => infer R ? R : never;
```

I am not sure why we need *ExtractInstanceType*  & why we don't want to just use IStaff:

```
  class UserFactory {
  static getUser(k: Keys) : IStaff {
    return new userMap[k]();
  }
```

I am also confused as to what Keys is saying here, I thought it was  just one of the keys in the dictionary  that userMap can hold, which would be a string?

But when that method is used, is it is used with an object instance as it's parameter or is that not possible?

```
const manager = new Manager();
const anotherManger = UserFactory.getUser(manager);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure why we need ExtractInstanceType & why we don't want to just use IStaff?

Because the whole point of the `userMap` and the associated static method is to map names to *specific, concrete* classes, not the interface they implement. If any of those classes implement class-specific stuff on top of the general IStaff interface (and they almost certainly will) your code would be littered with `instanceof` or other checks every time you called a method not in `IStaff` if you didn't nip it in the bud by narrowing the type with that static method to satisfy the compiler.

> I thought it was just one of the keys in the dictionary that userMap can hold, which would be a string?

As I suggested in the comments on my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690959/creating-a-factory-in-typescript-using-infer-and-typeof) I think the problem is that you are still conflating *types* and *values*. TBF it doesn't help that there's some overlap.

Consider the string 'a'. In Typescript, there is the *value* 'a' but there is also the *literal type 'a'*, which is a subset of type `string`:

```js
type a = 'a'
let a: a = 'a'
let s: string = a // note, variable a not string literal a!
const foo = {
  a: 1
}

console.log(foo[a]) // 1
console.log(foo[s]) // type error!

// ok, let's try the string literal 'a'
s = 'a'
console.log(foo[s]) // same type error!
// eff
```

Since `a` is literally 'a' we can index `foo` with it. But `s` is a mutable binding to a string, and you can't index `foo` with any old string even though we set the *value* to 'a', and even though we set it to the *variable* `a` which has *type a*, `s` is **still** a *string* the compiler has no way to guarantee that we don't re-assign a non-a value. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDkMkCgA2FiwFywWVU2ygGd8zgAnASwDsBzQmNAYwHt6qoAzDjoQDeaKHigBGNAF807LmQ5YAdBg6MAFPw4BtGAF0AlPO5KIq9VoE6yRtEA)

Types may look like values, and in certain contexts might have the exact same *appearance* as values, but they are **not** values, nor are values types. Moving right along...

For an object literal we know at compile-time the keys in the object, so if we have a foo object `{a: 'hi', b: 5}` then `keyof typeof foo` is `'a' | 'b'`. N.B. those are strings, but in this case they're *types*, NOT Javascript *values*. The method in the blog post constrains the values that the `k` parameter can be passed to be only values in the compile-time known keys of the `userMap`.

> But when that method is used, is it is used with an object instance as it's parameter or is that not possible?

Oh, it's *possible* to alter the method to work that way, it's just kinda pointless. If you have a reference to an instance, you already have a reference to its constructor you don't need a lookup table to make another one:

```js
class Foo {}

const foo = new Foo()
const bar = new (foo.constructor as any)()
bar instanceof Foo // true
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=43&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8C+Aodx4DsIBdoAzRaAXmhwFMB3ORACgEotcDoAjMAJ3MtugMS8AHTY8+bgFdg+eL0jQwOAJ5Nm6IA)

Again, the point of the `userMap` and that static method that accesses it is for the factory to be able to look up the correct user class by *string name*.

Comment: Thanks, that part about the constructor is useful, I didn't know I could do that. I just read the two links you provided and they are helpful but I will need to read them again. I am going to keep coming back and forth with more question I am sure but I'll take a little more time to read more about types in TS.   Do  these playgrounds or any other tools allow me to "inspect"/"analyze" these types with real code (e.g the conditional types in actual use), stepping through what is going on with the type system live?

Comment: @JC1700 It's not the full-featured interactive debugger it sounds like you want, but you *can* hover over variables (including types) in the playground to get a tooltip with what the compiler thinks they are.